# Compose MMS and launch to phone messaging app in React Native / ExpoKit

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using react-native-share's shareSingle to launch directly into social media apps and would like to do the same to the default messaging app to send an MMS on iOS and Android.  It seems simple to do SMS for text, but impossible to do an MMS for image.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Looked at the new-ish Share functionality in Expo, searched Node libraries, Google, etc... to no avail.